# Firebase Device Lab - how can I run cross app tests

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I'm interested in running some UIAutomator tests in the Firebase Test Lab: One of our tests we want to do involves functionality in 2 different apps.

So our process locally is:

1. Install app A
2. Install app B
3. Install the intrumentation apk

Run the instruentation step.

However, with the gcloud commands, it looks like we can only upload 1 app apk and 1 test apk.

Is there a way to do multiple apk testing in the Test Lab?

Answer (score 0):

Installing additional APKs is supported in gcloud beta:

```
gcloud beta firebase test android run \
    --app=path/to/app1.apk \
    --test=path/to/test.apk \
    --additional-apks=path/to/app2.apk,path/to/app3.apk \
    ...other options here...
```

You might need to install the beta component with `gcloud components install beta` or the package manager of your OS distribution.